# How to build an array or collection

Tags: arrays, collections, series, pine-script

I'd like to build a collection of several last highs and access all of them like I could in an array.
How do I do that? My code looks like this:

```
var float lastHigh = 0
if (highfound)
    lastHigh := high
```

Now I try this:

```
x := lastHigh[3]
```

... but x is only the LAST lastHigh value then (like it would be lastHigh[1]).
So lastHigh is just a "flat" variable, right? How can I collect more than one last high?

Comment: Arrays and similar data structers are not supported by pine-script yet.

Comment: I know, there are no arrays in pine yet. But there has to be a solution for the above problem..?

Comment: There are only 2 workarounds, afaik: multiply variables and code, or use a pseudo-array as RicardoSantos has done [here](https://www.tradingview.com/script/sQxpiBL8-RS-Function-Pseudo-Array-Example/).

Comment: Or tell us what your end goal is then maybe there is some other solution for your problem.

Comment: I just want to check if the actual bar's high is even higher than all the least (for example 5) pivot highs identified on the chart!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with the next approach:

```
//@version=4
study("Three last highs", overlay=true)

// here goes the logic for finding the high
// NOTE: if you are updating this function,
// then it should return either new value for the array or n/a. 
// Because the non-n/a value will be added to the array and the oldest removed
getNewHighOrNa() =>
    pivothigh(high, 3, 3)

newHigh = getNewHighOrNa()




// ======= Array lifecicle =========
ARRAY_LENGTH = 5

arrayCell = label(na)
if bar_index < ARRAY_LENGTH
    arrayCell := label.new(0, 0)
    label.set_y(arrayCell, 0)
else
    if na(newHigh)
        val = label.get_y(arrayCell[1])
        for i = 2 to ARRAY_LENGTH
            v = label.get_y(arrayCell[i])
            label.set_y(arrayCell[i-1], v)
        arrayCell := arrayCell[ARRAY_LENGTH]
        label.set_y(arrayCell, val)
    else
        arrayCell := arrayCell[ARRAY_LENGTH]
        label.set_y(arrayCell, newHigh)
// ==================================

// Array getter by index. Note, that numeration is right to left
// so 0 is the last bar (current) and 1 it's a left to current bar
get(index) => label.get_y(arrayCell[index])

// example of using of the array for calculation average of all elements of the array
mean() =>
    sum = 0.0
    for i = 0 to ARRAY_LENGTH - 1
        sum := sum + get(i) / ARRAY_LENGTH
    sum
plot(mean(), title="Mean", color=color.green)

// example of finding of max value in the array
max_high() =>
    max = get(0)
    for i = 1 to ARRAY_LENGTH - 1
        v = get(i)
        if v > max
            max := v
    max
plot(max_high(), title="MAX", color=color.red)


// the rest is just checking that the code works:
plot(get(0))
plot(get(1))
plot(get(2))
plot(get(3))
plot(get(4))

// mark the bars where we found new highs
plotshape(not na(newHigh), style=shape.flag)
```

I tried to make it easier, but because of pine's restriction, didn't managed it. But this code works and you are getting 3 last local highs and can iterate over them. Hope I've got your question right.

Comment: Ok... thanks, I'll have a look. What I want to do is simply calculate the highest value of the last 5 pivot highs, and a pivot high is simply identified by the built in function: pivothigh(high, 3, 3)

Comment: I've made the changes. Note, that there are commentaries how to work with an 'array'. Also, I added example with average calculation and finding of max to show how to use the array with loops and general logic in work with it. Bear in mind, that there is restriction in working with drawings - they can break the array, so it'd be better not to use them with the array. If you need more values in the array (I suppose, up to 50 are allowed) - you just change the variable `ARRAY_LENGTH`  to new length of the array.

Comment: Looks great! Thank you! :-) The only thing I'm not content with is, you shift the array elements with every bar that comes in which has no new high. So when there IS a new high, you throw away not necessarily the very first high (which was found longest time ago), it may be the third or any other (because all the high's positions in the array have shiftet until then). But I really like the concept! :-) And I see it takes only minor changes to correct that behavior (shift all array elements one position only when a new element is added, so that really the oldest gets lost). Thank you so much!!

Comment: This is an amazing piece of code, Michel. How ingenious! Respect.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `highfound` function, not demonstrated in the original question, results either false or true, your code should work by removing the `:` from the `x` variable:

```
x = lastHigh[3]
```

The following worked just fine for me:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

var float lastHigh = 0
if (close>open)
    lastHigh := high

x = lastHigh[3]
plot(x, color=color.red)
```

Comment: Thank you. It's not really I'm looking for, as "lastHigh[3]" gives me not exactly the third least last high (wich was identified somewhere on the chart)... I just get the value of the "lastHigh" variable 3 bars ago (which also may be, for example, the second least last high). But thank you for your contribution! :) Maybe I try so solve my problem that way.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've misinterpreted your question. I see it is resolved above. Thanks for voting up even though :)